# gem install with archflag and version mysql2

Tags: ruby, mysql2

frustrated. Is this wrong?

env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql2 --version '0.2.6' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config

want to install 0.2.6

Why the hell it keeps installing 0.3.2????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" sudo gem install mysql2 --version '=0.2.6' -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

note the

> --version '=0.2.6'

Answer (score 0):

hm so it should be '= 0.2.6'

But now I got

Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter`

Alrighty time to reinstall everything... again